# How do i get the information of Network Utilization , Link speed and state of Adapter as shown in the Task manager's Networking tab?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to show the same information in my win form program as shown in the task manager.
[image]

I want to show the same information for **remote computer** also.
If i have an ip of any other system which is connected to my system then i can also get the same information of those system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting simple information about network adapters you should use [NetworkInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx). It provides configuration and statistical information for a network interface.

```
public void EchoNetworkInformation()
{
   System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] nics;
   nics = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
       foreach (var nic in nics)
        {
            if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                continue;

           Console.WriteLine("Adapter name: " + nic.Name);
           Console.WriteLine("Link speed: " + nic.Speed);
           Console.WriteLine("State: " + nic.OperationalStatus);

           var utilization = GetNetworkUtilization(nic.Description);
           Console.WriteLine("Network utilization", utilization);

        }
}
```

About network utilization - it's more complicated. It uses the following formula for the network utilization:

```
%utilization = ((8*(dataSent + dataReceived))/bandwidth*time_in_sec)) * 100
```

I found great [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20080315235958/http://nayyeri.net/blog/how-to-calculate-network-utilization-in-net/) about calculation. You can find here some useful information.
To reduce your time - you can use this code, which resolve this task. It use [PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides performance information.

```
/// <summary> Calculate network utilization </summary>
/// <param name="networkCard">Description of network card from NetworkInterface</param>
/// <returns>NetworkUtilization</returns>
public static double GetNetworkUtilization(string networkCard)
{
   const int numberOfIterations = 10;

   // Condition networkCard;
   networkCard = networkCard.Replace("\\", "_");
   networkCard = networkCard.Replace("/", "_");
   networkCard = networkCard.Replace("(", "[");
   networkCard = networkCard.Replace(")", "]");
   networkCard = networkCard.Replace("#", "_");

   var bandwidthCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Current Bandwidth", networkCard);

   var bandwidth = bandwidthCounter.NextValue();

   var dataSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", networkCard);
   var dataReceivedCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", networkCard);

   float sendSum = 0;
   float receiveSum = 0;

   for (var index = 0; index < numberOfIterations; index++)
   {
      sendSum += dataSentCounter.NextValue();
      receiveSum += dataReceivedCounter.NextValue();
   }

   var dataSent = sendSum;
   var dataReceived = receiveSum;

   double utilization = (8 * (dataSent + dataReceived)) / (bandwidth * numberOfIterations) * 100;

   return utilization;
}
```

Comment: I run the code provided by you but after giving the information of two adapters , showing an error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll) in NextValue().

Comment: I need to show only physical adapter details not virtual adapters as you can see in the figure.

Comment: Can you give me type of your adapter, where you got error? nic.GetType();

Comment: Yes , its tunnel and description is Microsoft ISATAP Adapter

Comment: You can check type and exclude them from results

Comment: So how can i know which type should exclude? As i am a beginner i don't have much idea about these network adapters.

Comment: You can use Wereless80211 and Ethernet.

Comment: ok , this code is working but my another question was to get these information of another PC Connected through LAN . Do you have any idea?